# Contar cuantos elementos con una misma clase hay con JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Quisiera saber como puedo **contar** los elementos que hay con una misma clase en un HTML a poder ser con **JQuery** sino con **JavaScript** también me vale.

Gracias!

**Ejemplo**

```
div class="hola"
div class="hola"
div class="hola"
```

> Un script que dijese que hay 3 elementos con la clase "hola".

**¿Que he probado?**

```
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("orange"); 
var numDivs = divs.length; 
var contadorNaranja = 0; 
for(var i = 0; i < numDivs; i++){
  if(divs[i].className == "orange") 
  contadorNaranja++;
}
var puntos1 = contadorNaranja;

document.getElementById("jugador1puntos").innerHTML = "Jugador1: "+puntos1;
```

Comment: Sería ideal que añadieses lo que hayas intentado y los problemas/dificultades que te estés encontrando. Lee [ask]  y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información y recomendaciones.

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? Hay varias formas de hacer esto, pero sería bueno siempre que muestres el intento que has hecho. Saludos.

Comment: Ese codigo qué problemas te da? Y por qué en vez de `ByTagName` no usas `ByClassName`?

Comment: De pronto el condicional que haces no funcione, ya que `className` puede no ser igual a orange, mejor pregunta `if (divs[i].classList.contains('orange'))` esto funcionará mas, pero dado tu código no tiene sentido aumentar el contador naranja, ya que si obtuviste `n` cantidad de divs al hacer el `getElementByClassName` entonces ese `length` viene siendo el valor final de la variable `contadorNaranja`, es decir, no es necesario hacer el `for`

Comment: @GermanAlzate editó su pregunta con mi comentario anterior lo cual carece de sentido. al hacer el `byclassname` el for, como dices, no tiene sentido alguno .

Comment: @rafemo las dos opciones que dices que intentaste funcionan sin problemas y sin ningún tipo de cambio ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p4hw3mzx/)). ¿cuál es el problema que te encontrabas con esas dos soluciones?

Comment: El problema era un fallo mío en el cual contaba bien con .length() pero al no haber ningun setInterval, click o semejantes el numero era siempre 0 y pensaba que no funcionaba, perdón por las molestias.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### Con javascript

Puedes utilizar la propiedad [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) e imprimir su length

```js
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName("hola").length;
console.log("Hay " + divs + " elementos");
```

```html
<div class="hola"></div>
<div class="hola"></div>
<div class="hola"></div>
<div class="hola"></div>
<div class="hola"></div>
<div class="hola"></div>
```

#### Con jQuery

Puedes utilizar la propiedad [`toArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/toArray/) que convierte en un arreglo el resultado para su manipulación y puedes imprimir su length para saber cuantos elementos tiene.

```js
var $divs = $(".hola").toArray().length;
console.log("Hay " + $divs + " elementos");
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="hola"></div>
<div class="hola"></div>
<div class="hola"></div>
<div class="hola"></div>
<div class="hola"></div>
```

Si por otro lado lo único que necesitas es saber cuantos elementos existen, se puede utilizar `$(".hola").length`

Comment: Una pregunta: ¿Por qué usar `toArray()`? No veo diferencia a usarlo o no en este caso

Comment: @blonfu vi que estaba trabajando con un bucle, pensé que le serviría mas para iterarlo. Pero tienes razón en este caso no hay diferencia

Answer (score 10):

La propiedad length te regresará la cantidad de elementos con esa clase

`$(".hola").length`

Espero haber ayudado

Saludos

Answer (score 7):

Lo que quieres hacer es muy fácil. Y se puede hacer perfectamente con JS puro. Usar jQuery para esto sería a mi juicio una *involución*. Lo que quiero decir es que el código funciona mejor y más rápido con JS puro que con jQuery.

En JS puro hay al menos dos formas de hacerlo:

- con `getElementsByClassName` usándolo adecuadamente
- con `querySelectoAll` (sería la forma más óptima, sólo que la comptabilidad es de un 90%... tampoco está mal).

Te dejo un ejemplo con las dos posibilidades:

```js
/*Forma 1: con getElementsByClassName*/
var divsOrange = document.getElementsByClassName("orange");
var totalNaranja = divsOrange.length;

document.getElementById("jugador1puntos").innerHTML = "Jugador1: " + totalNaranja;

/*Forma 2: con querySelectorAll*/

var divsRojo = document.querySelectorAll(".red");
var totalRojo = divsRojo.length;

document.getElementById("jugador2puntos").innerHTML = "Jugador2: " + totalRojo;
```

```html
<div class="orange"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="orange"></div>
<div class="blue"></div>
<div class="orange"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
<div class="green"></div>
<div class="red"></div>

<hr />
<div id="jugador1puntos"></div>
<div id="jugador2puntos"></div>
```

> **NOTA**: Escribí esta respuesta al ver que el código de tu pregunta estaba originalmente en JS puro, con la intención de hacer ver que
>   esto es posible muy fácilmente sin tener que recurrir a librerías
>   externas.

Answer (score -5):

```
$('.hola').size();
```

Bastante intuitivo, no crees?

Comment: `size()` está desaprobado desde jQuery 1.8.