# ¿Contar inputs dinamicos con jQuery?

Tags: html, jquery

quiero contar unos inputs dinamicos que genero con este codigo:

```
function AgregarPagoFechaVencimiento() {
            var fecha = $("#FechaVencimientoPago").val();
            var fechaFormato = formato(fecha);
            var div = $("<div class='col-sm-3' id='pago"+ fechaFormato +"'>");
            var divClose = $("</div>");
            var divPago = $("<div class ='form-group'>");
            var label = $("<label class='control-label'>Pago " + fecha + "</label>");
            var inputPago = $("<input class= 'form-control pago'>").attr("type", "text");
            div.append(divPago).append(label).append(inputPago).append(divClose).append(divClose);

            return div;
        }
```

Y estoy tratando de contar cuantos hay generados con esto:

```
var count = $(".form-control pago").length;
        console.log(count);
```

intente esto otro:

var count = $(".pago").length;
console.log(count);

y esto:

```
var count= document.GetElementsByClass(".pago").length;
```

¿Alguna sugerencia de que pueda implementar para que me regrese la cuenta de cuantos elementos generados hay?

Edit: HTML donde va incrustado el elemento dinamico:

```
<div class="row m-t-10" id="fechaPagoContainer"></div>
```

y este es la funcion que manda a llamar a AgregarPagoFechaVencimiento();

```
function AgregarTextBoxFechaVencimiento() {
            var div = GenerarElementosDinamicosFechaVencimiento("");
            var pagoFecha = AgregarPagoFechaVencimiento("");
            $("#divCompraFechaVencimientoContainer").append(div);
            $("#fechaPagoContainer").append(pagoFecha);
            $("#FechaVencimientoPago").val("");
            $("#btnAgregarFechaVencimientoPago").attr("disabled", "true");

            var count = $(".form-control pago").length;
            console.log(count);
        }
```

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el HTML donde va a ir incrustado eso?  Lo digo porque ahí tienes un problema de delegación de eventos, pues tal como lo estás poniendo parece que se ejecute el count solo durante la carga de la página, y no en respuesta a un evento determinado, por lo tanto es probable que aún no haya ninguno que contar en ese momento y de ahí que no consigas el resultado esperado.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Contar cuantos elementos con una misma clase hay con JQuery](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/156609/contar-cuantos-elementos-con-una-misma-clase-hay-con-jquery)

Comment: Dejame revisar si lo pongo dentro de un evento tal vez si cambie

Comment: <div class="row m-t-10" id="fechaPagoContainer"></div>

Comment: No pongas código en los comentarios. Recuerda que puedes [edit] la pregunta las veces que sea necesario.

Comment: okay, ya lo puse masterguru

Comment: ¿has probado mi respuesta?  ¿lo tienes claro?  ¿te ha funcionado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto seguramente es suficiente para contarlos:

```
  var count = $(".pago").length;
  console.log(count);
```

pero debe ir asociada a un evento, sino tan solo se ejecuta durante la carga inicial de la página.

Posible solución:

1. Lo ponemos en una función para que no se ejecute durante la carga, sino cuando invoquemos a la función:

```
function contarClasesPago() {
  var count = $(".pago").length
  console.log(count)
}
```

2. Lo agregamos como evento a un botón, en este caso onclick:

```
<button id="botoncontarClasesPago" onclick="contarClasesPago()">
  Cuenta clases Pago
</button>
```

3. O bien con jquery y el evento click asociado al botón (todo junto):

```
===== html =======
<button id="botoncontarClasesPago">
  Cuenta clases Pago
</button>
====== javascript ======
$('#botoncontarClasesPago').click( function() {
  var count = $(".pago").length
  console.log(count)
})
```

4. O bien llamando a la función antes definida:

```
$('#botoncontarClasesPago').click( function() {
    contarClasesPago()
})
```

También podrías usar *addEventListener* con javascript puro, pero ya que usas jquery no hace falta.

Comment: Okay si me arroja en la consola la cuenta, ahora si, solo que cuando vuelvo a poner en la consola console.log(count)  me arroja 0 pero lo importante es que ya tengo el dato jeje

Comment: si te refieres a que intentas hacer un `console.log(count)` desde el interprete de mandatos de la consola de tu navegador y sale 0 es porque **count** esta solo definido dentro de una función o un evento (no se cual de las cosas que he respondido estas usando).  Supongo que si quitas el **var count** fuera de ellas se volverá global y lo podrás hacer a pelo en la consola